# system.data.datarowview in each row of DataGrid when binding to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind to a `DataTable` to a `DataGrid` in wpf.

Here is my code:

My Model:

```
private DataTable _runNumbers;
public DataTable RunNumbers
{
    set
    {
        _runNumbers = value;
    }
    get
    {
        if (_runNumbers == null) { _runNumbers = new DataTable("RunNumbers"); }
        return _runNumbers;
        }
    }


public RunNumberModel() //Constructor
{
    RunNumbers.Columns.Add(" ", typeof(string));
    RunNumbers.Columns[" "].ReadOnly = true;
    RunNumbers.Rows.Add("Test");
}
```

My view:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RunNumbers.RunNumbers}" />
```

Which produces: [image: Application]

I cannot seem to figure out how to show the value of the cell rather then `System.Data.DataRowView` - I was thinking perhaps I need a `DataTemplate` of some sort but I am not sure how I would set this up.

I have looked at many other posts online and have had no success.

If anyone knows the problem I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you use a valid column name like for example "x":

```
public RunNumberModel() //Constructor
{
    RunNumbers.Columns.Add("x", typeof(string));
    RunNumbers.Columns["x"].ReadOnly = true;
    RunNumbers.Rows.Add("Test");
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! Do you of anyway I can have no column name?

Comment: @Alfie: `RunNumbers.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());`?

Comment: That gives a column name of "Column1"

Comment: Yes. So? Either you specify an explicit column name or you don't?

Comment: No sorry, I mean how I can have no column name in the `DataGrid` for this specific column, so the cell is just blank?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have new issue.